# iOS 7 3D gallery transition effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

How can I implement in iOS 7 the transition effect in the link below ?

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/3DGallery/index.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel to see how it's done - you could in fact just use this library in your code.